# Help with a copy between buffers using memcpy C

Tags: c, memcpy

I need to copy the content of one buffer to another one in blocks of *n* bytes (*n* might vary), several times to check the cache performance.

I use memcpy, but I'm afraid I'm not getting successful results. The block size is variable from some kbytes to Mbytes. And I have to reserve the maximum block to use (long double).

I'm a little lost in the copy. I'm just wondering if somebody has faced this problem, and can help me with some tips or pseudo code.

I edit the topic to include some code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp= fopen("part1.dat", "w");
    struct timeval time, oldtime;
    float segundos, microsegundos, total;
    //        float rendimiento;    
    pid_t pid;
    struct sched_param parametros;
    int i, v,p;
    char buffer1[100024];
    char buffer2[100024];

    pid = getpid();
    parametros.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_FIFO, &parametros);
    p=0;

    gettimeofday(&oldtime, NULL);

    for (i=1;i<65;i++)
    {
        size_t datos=i*1024;
        for (v=0; p>i;v++)
        {
             memcpy(buffer1, buffer2, datos);
             p=(MAX_SIZE/i*1024);

        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    segundos = (float) (time.tv_sec - oldtime.tv_sec);
    microsegundos = (float) (time.tv_usec - oldtime.tv_usec);
    total = (float) ((segundos * 1000000 + microsegundos));


    //            printf ("Dimension %d \t Tiempo 1: %.2f \t Fallos Metodo 1:%d \t Tiempo 2: %.2f \t Fallos Metodo 2:%d \t Multiplica: %f \t Rendimiento: %.2f\n", i, total, fallos1, total2, fallos2, iteraciones, rendimiento);
    //              fprintf (fp, "%d \t %.3f %.3f %.3f\n", i, total, total2,rendimiento);


    fclose(fp);
    printf("Se ha creado el archivo de datos: part1.dat\n");

    return(0);
}
```

The idea is to copy from buffer1 to buffer2, in datos blocks 'p' times, in this case is supposed to be done 256000 times (i=1, datos=1024).

Comment: You don't really explain what you are having trouble doing? Are you having trouble getting 'blocks' to copy between? call malloc(). Are you having trouble measuring the time taken? you'll need to tell us what platform if you want <1ms accuracy.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not being so clear, I don't know exactly where is the fault. I define two buffer (char *buff[n]) and then the data block array (long double block[]), then I just want to copy a block of data from one buffer to another 'x' times. For example if the block is 1024 bytes, do the copy 10 times.

Comment: But you know there is a fault. What are the symptoms? What happens or happens not? Can you show us some code? How far are you? Or do you have trouble with writing a for-loop?

Comment: I edited the post to include some code, the problem is I want to reserve like 10Mb for the buffers and then vary the block size, now it's fix in 1024 bytes, so I need to write the loop to do it x times.
Thanks for the help

Comment: The third argument to memcpy is the number of bytes you want to copy, but datos is an array... Try memcpy(buffer1, buffer2, 1024); Note that datos is then not used at all and the number to copy should not exceed 2048, else you have undefined behaviour. Maybe what you meant to do is size_t datos = 1024;

Comment: Woah, what a mess. Take the calculation of p out of the inner loop, define MAX_SIZE and correct the conditions and calculations. You probably mean v<p and p=(MAX_SIZE/(i*1024))?

Answer (score 2):

A problem with the code - the inner for() loop won't execute.  You are initializing p to zero

```
p = 0;
```

and then the loop condition compares p > i where i ranges from 1 to 64.

```
for (i=1;i<65;i++)
{
   size_t datos=i*1024;
   for (v=0; p>i;v++)
   {
      .....
```

So memcpy() is never actually called...

You also said:

> The idea is to copy from buffer1 to
>   buffer2, in datos blocks 'p' times, in
>   this case is supposed to be done
>   256000 times (i=1, datos=1024).

memcpy() takes the destination array as the first argument and the source as second.  Your parameters are backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't use `memcpy()` for this, since you don't know how it acts internally. It might for instance touch memory out of order, which could perhaps make your measurements odd. It would of course be assumed to do "the best thing", but your task seems to imply that you don't care. :)

So just use a straight copying loop, maybe rounding out non-aligned accesses first (which is another thing `memcpy()` very probably already does).

Also, you can't measure memory block sizes using a non-integer type such as `double`. You should use `size_t`.

Comment: I believe memmove() is guaranteed to copy memory in order, since it can be used to copy overlapping regions. Would this help?

Comment: Hi unwind, I don't want to know the memory block size, just copy it from one buffer to another. The porpuse is to see that when the block size increases, the data to move doesn't fit in the cache memory, so the time spend in the copy increases

Comment: @Peter: I realize that, I just pointed out that you should use size_t since you mentioned "long double" for block sizes.

Comment: memmove( ) is not guaranteed to copy in order, only to do the right thing if the buffers alias each other.  Among other things, it would be completely valid for memmove to check for aliasing and call memcpy if they don't alias.